# Xcode 15 replaced Symbol navigator with Bookmark Navigator. What's the way to access class hierarchy?

Tags: xcode, xcode15

I recently updated to Xcode 15 and observed that Symbol Navigator has been replaced with Bookmark Navigator.

I've been trying to locate it without success.

With the Symbol Navigator apparently gone, is there a method to view the class hierarchy and a comprehensive list of all project and linked framework symbols in a single location?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are now 3 menu items in the find menu (click right on any symbol in an editor). They are Find Ancestor Types, Find Descendent Types, and Find Conforming Types. These will bring up Symbol Browser. Make sure you set the search scope just below the search field.